# Smslib Not reading sms from dongle

Tags: smslib

Dear mate i have implement all the needed jars and smslib files as per the description but i am always getting error as below can you please let me know how to solve this is issue as its getting irritated please would be glad to receive ur help.

```
WARNING:  RXTX Version mismatch
    Jar version = RXTX-2.2-20081207 Cloudhopper Build rxtx.cloudhopper.net
    native lib Version = RXTX-2.1-7pre16
>>> Gateway Status change for modem.com4, OLD: STOPPED -> NEW: RESTART
>>> Gateway Status change for modem.com4, OLD: RESTART -> NEW: STOPPING
>>> Gateway Status change for modem.com4, OLD: STOPPING -> NEW: STOPPED
org.smslib.GatewayException: Comm library exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: gnu.io.NoSuchPortException
    at org.smslib.modem.SerialModemDriver.connectPort(SerialModemDriver.java`enter code here`:102)
    at org.smslib.modem.AModemDriver.connect(AModemDriver.java:114)
    at org.smslib.modem.ModemGateway.startGateway(ModemGateway.java:189)
    at org.smslib.Service$1Starter.run(Service.java:277)**
```